# How do I turn this into a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, graph

I'm trying to create an org chart based on a model that references itself through an attribute called `reports_to`. I don't know how many levels down the org chart will go, so I feel like a recursive function makes sense. Here's some code that works at the moment:

```
top_level = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=None)
org_chart = {}
for person in top_level:
    org_chart[person] = {}
    if person.has_direct_reports():
        direct_reports = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=person)
        for p in direct_reports:
            org_chart[person][p] = {}
            if p.has_direct_reports():
                direct_reports_2 = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=p)
                for q in direct_reports_2:
                    org_chart[person][p][q] = {}
                        # ... and so on
```

This results in a shell output like this:

```
>>> pp.pprint(org_chart)
{   <Person: Joe Boss>: {   <Person: John Doe>: {   <Person: John Doe Jr>: {   },
                                                          <Person: Jane Doe>: {   }}},
    <Person: Partner Mary>: {}}
```

Which is correct. Shown cleaner:

```
Joe Boss
- John Doe
-- John Doe Jr
-- Jane Doe
Partner Mary
```

I've been trying to convert this code to a recursive function, but my brain just won't get around the problem. Thanks for any advice or help in solving this!

Edit. Here's the code I'm trying to make work, but I'm falling over myself in the process:

```
def direct_reports_r(person):
    if person.has_direct_reports():
        direct_reports = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=person)
        for person in direct_reports:
            org_chart[person] = {}
            if person.has_direct_reports():
                direct_reports = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=person)
                org_chart[person] = direct_reports_r(person)
            else:
                return person
    else:
        return False

top_level = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=None)
org_chart = {}
for person in top_level:
    org_chart[person] = {}
    # recursion
    org_chart[person][direct_reports_r(person)] = {}
```

Comment: Your really gotta use Trees: http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch21.html

Comment: Sounds like a graph search (EDIT: actually yes it's just a tree traversal, since there are no loops). Anyway it would be easier if you refactored `Person` so it had a `direct_reports` property/method - the opposite direction of `reports_to`, but could be a one-to-many. Then also `if person.has_direct_reports(); direct_reports = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=person); for p2 in direct_reports` reduces to simply `for p2 in person.direct_reports()`

Comment: I haven't heard of graph search or trees! So much learning to go do. Thank you.

Comment: There's a bug in your code: you redeclare `for person in direct_reports` but that shadows the `person` it was called with. Best to call it `subordinate` or `dr` or `p2` or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passed lists are mutable, as well as dictionaries so when you pass it into an argument, it's by reference.  Here's an example you can play with to achieve the desired result.

```
top_level = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=None)
org_chart = {}

def init_org_chart(reports, arg):
    for person in reports:
        arg[person] = {}
        if person.has_direct_reports():
            direct_reports = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=person)
            init_org_chart(direct_reports, arg[person])

init_org_chart(top_level, org_chart)
```

Comment: I was thinking passing `org_chart` into the recursion might work. Let me digest this, but it works for me!

Comment: Both versions of this answer work for me. I like that this version puts everything into the function, rather than having any for loops outside of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this code works.

```
def foo(person, tmp_root):
    tmp_root[person] = {}
    if person.has_direct_reports():
        direct_reports = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=person)
        for p in direct_reports:
            foo(p, tmp_root[person])

org_chart = {}
top_level = Person.objects.filter(reports_to=None)
for person in top_level:
    foo(person, org_chart)
```